# Why is /k/ sometimes spelt with a C, and sometimes with a K?

Tags: pronunciation, history, phonetics, historical-change, phonemes

This may sound silly. But I'm really confused why, when we pronounce (the phoneme) /k/, we sometimes spell it with a `C` and sometimes with a `K` (sometimes with `CK`).
Why wasn't 'k' used instead, in such words as: car, cake, etc...?

Comment: Because our writing system is largely derived from the Roman alphabet, which didn't originally have a *K*; it got that letter from Greek (which, in turn, didn't really have a *C*).

Comment: I think the whole question of why orthography and spoken usage are (or *become*) so out of step is Too Broad. But on this *specific* point I think it makes more sense to ask why *the sound* **/k/** is sometimes written using *the letter* **c**, rather than why that letter is sometimes pronounced that way.

Comment: _c_ is generally pronounced like _k_ when followed by vowels _a_, _o_, or _u_, it's pronounced like _s_ when followed by _e_, _i_, or _y_.

Comment: English has a number of letters that are pronounced differently depending on their context. This is most common with vowels, which have long and short forms (and variations within them), but there are also some consonants that vary.

Comment: You're working from the wrong concept. Letters don't make sounds; sounds are represented in letters. So what you mean is why, when we say /k/, we sometimes spell it with a `C` and sometimes with a `K` (and of course sometimes with `CK`, for good measure). And the answer is that we are in the habit of spelling words in certain ways, because of how they were spelled and sometimes because of how they were pronounced in a different language, at the time and place they were borrowed into English. And not from how they're pronounced now in modern English. It's 400-year-old software, for Pete's sake.

Comment: @MattGutting That’s not really right. The Roman alphabet derives from the Greek one anyway, and the earliest texts written in it (in early Latin) had both K (before /a/), Q (before back vowels), and C (elsewhere). The evolution was for C to start replacing K; and then later on, when they started borrowing Greek words at a stage where Latin was already a thriving language of literature, they started representing the Greek kappa with Ks. (And technically, Greek did have a C: gamma. C was originally a G, with the extra stroke in the G being added by the Romans later for disambiguation.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet point. But as I understand it, by the time people started using the Roman alphabet to write (what became) English, *C* was much more predominant in Latin orthography than *K*; and that preference was carried over into writing English.

Comment: @MattGutting Absolutely—K was all but gone from the Roman alphabet in its normal usage by the third or even fourth century BC if memory serves. Classical Latin used K only in learned Greek borrowings.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Exactly - "Kalendae" is the only more-or-less widely used word I can think of with a K.

Comment: 400-year-old software  -  I like it.  @John Lawler, are you going to lobby for an upgrade?